# is it safe to fetch an image on plain http on a bank's homebanking website?

Tags: security

I ask here instead of https://security.stackexchange.com/ because I dont think this question is on a professional level.

I just saw something weird on my bank's website, they are fetching an image from another domain, using http instead of https , on firefox it raises a security "mixed content" alert, on chrome it just shows up an alert on the security tab.

This is the site: https://www.bancoprovincia.com.ar/Principal/BipPersonal
[image]

The unsafe content (an image) happens to be on the page just before the user logs in to his home banking, I was worried that some attacker could intercept the content and replace it with something that could be a security risk.

Any chance this is a security risk for the bank and it's clients?.

Comment: There is a reason for the "mixed content" alert. If I was responsible for that website, I'd make sure it shows up without security alerts. Even if that image is not a problem or a potential attack vector, it shows a definite lack of attention to detail. In fact, on a banking website, I'd rather not have them include anything third-party, even over HTTPS.

Comment: Not much of one, but it shows they're irresponsible. Also probably better asked on [Security.SE].

Comment: Absolutely, it's also something really easy to fix, just serve the image on their server instead of a third party server with no certificate.

However i'm worried that this might pose an actual risk and i want to know if any known attacks could exploit this, or maybe it's already an attack in progress of some kind.

Comment: If you control the user’s connection, you can replace the image. If it were on the same domain and they had set a cookie without the `Secure` flag, it would be at risk, but it’s not. Browser/PNG decoder vulnerabilities are about the only other thing as far as I know. It leaks more information about your browsing, but that’s true of any unencrypted connection you make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a direct vulnerability, but still bad practice.

Some risks that come to mind:

- An attacker having access to users' connections (man in the middle) could replace the image with a malicious one, exploiting potentially zero-day (as yet unknown) flaws in browser or operating system image processor libraries. This could lead to remote code execution on the client.
- Replacing the image could also be used to facilitate phishing. The malicious image could tell the user to call a phone number because of some kind of a problem, etc.
- It is an information leak. An attacker may receive information about users browsing to the bank website, also if the image is in a header included on all pages, they may receive information about what the user does. This is inherently the case for every external site that has its images linked even over https, but over http this also applies to any MitM attacker.
- It is a potential availability problem. If the image on the external site times out (waits too long to download), the page will not load for some time in some browsers and an attacker could exploit that. However, this I think is not affected by the image being served on plain http, it would affect an externally linked https image as well I think.
- It's also a very bad practice, because instead of strengthening good security practices in users like always checking browser indications of a secure website, it is telling them that it's ok if there are warnings. It is not.